# How to set permissions for Android using Phonegap Build?

Tags: android, cordova, permissions, phonegap-build

I tried other solutions around here but no matter what I do the same permissions are asked during install of my app.
I tried removing a bunch of the "plugins" phonegap uses, namely: (from the config.xml)

```
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization"/>
```

Yet when I update my code and then try to install the apps it still asks for stuff like location.

Anyone who knows this?

Comment: Why do you remove plugins from config.xml? Config.xml is not the place where we place something related with plugins. Maybe you can remove your plugins using "cordova plugin remove" command. @TheGie

Answer (score 4):

It isn't the plugins that declare the permissions. The permissions are declared with [*feature*](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_features.md.html#Features) elements like

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
```

Comment: tried that. Didn't work. The default config.xml doesn't have any feature elements.

Comment: Nope, the default doesn't have so that all of them are included. That is how it is supposed to work (ask for **all** permissions). Adding these makes the app ask only for the permissions you actually want to and it works just fine. You can see the documentation [here](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_features.md.html#Features).

Comment: sanfor is correct. I'm a Phonegap Build developer - this is how it works. Once you get used to setting up a project you'll find it very easy, nice and easy.

Comment: When I add the <feature>s I want to the config.xml, but it'll still ask for all permissions. :(

Comment: Then your _config.xml_ isn't probably correctly loaded in the first place. Have you added `xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
` inside your _config.xml_ as _widget_ tags parameter as shown [here](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_basics.md.html#The%20Basics)?

Comment: Yes it's there. I can send you an e-mail with my current config.xml if you want.

Comment: @TheGie: Feel free, email is available on my profile.

Comment: @sanfor The documentation you pointed to says "Aside from the debug-server feature, the feature tag is essentially deprecated on PhoneGap Build since PhoneGap APIs were pluginized.Permissions are now generally managed by individual plugins, and application manifests and permissions can be modified directly using the config-file element. However for backwards-compatibility, they are still supported and map to device permissions on Android and Windows Phone 8:" This leads me to believe your suggested solution is a work-round, true?

Comment: @fiprojects: Yes that is the case nowadays. When I wrote this answer (over a year ago), though, it wasn't the case and you were required to specify the permissions by hand. The current system is somewhat better. Only thing problematic with it is that when there's plugins with multiple responsibilities, it might require more permissions than app actually uses.

Comment: The feature tag has been deprecated, see: http://phonegap.com/blog/2016/02/24/phonegap-build-confg-xml-now-required-and-other-updates/